# What are the flags behind the animal king?

Tags: portal-2

[image: animal king takeover]

In this image we see six flags behind the animal king.
I think I recognize some of them:
First - Argentina;
Third - Bulgaria;
Fifth - Sweden;
Sixth - Austria;

Am I correct, and which countries' flags are the second and fourth?

Comment: While removing the question about developer intent is appreciated, I'm still not sure that identifying real-world country flags is within Arqade's area of expertise.

Comment: For me looks like a legit question. Is not "why did they choose that flags?", is "what flags are there?". If there is a question like "why in thief 3 is a poster with the dead pilgrim god?" I'm sure an answer like "because u killed him in a previous game" would appear. Maybe is close to offtopic but... is between limits imo.

Answer (score 1):

From left to right:

- Argentina
- New Zealand
- Bulgaria
  _
- Bolivia
- Sweden
- Austria